# Proper HTML document outline with <h1> under some other heading

Tags: html

### Situation

In my page I have a markup similar to this:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a>
            <img src="./logo.svg" />
            <span class="hide">Site name</span>
        </a>

        <nav>
            <h2>Main site navigation</h2>
            ...
        </nav>

        <section>
            <h2>Section title</h2>
            ...
        </section>
    </header>

    <main>
        <!-- This is the main page title. -->
        <h1>Page title</h1>

        <section>
            <h2>Another section title</h2>
            ...
        </section>
        ...
    </main>

    <footer>
        ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

Which on screen should render as:

```
----------------------------
* Logo          Navigation *
*                          *   // Header
*      Section title       * 
----------------------------
*        Page title        *
*                          *
*   Another section title  *   // Main
*            ...           *
*                          *
----------------------------
*            ...           *   // Footer
----------------------------
```

The outline of this document looks like below and is not logically correct.

1. Main site navigation

   1. Section title
2. Page title

   1. Another section title

The problems with this situation are:

- `<h2>Main site navigation</h2>` is treated as the title for the whole page, while `<h1>Page title</h1>` should be this title
- `<h2>Main site navigation</h2>` opens new sectioning root and section with `<h2>Section title</h2>` heading is actually treated as sub-section of that root (which is not logically correct).

### Question

How can I achieve the logical outline?

1. Page title

   1. Main site navigation
   2. Section title
   3. Another section title

### Limitations

I can't move `<h1>` outside `<main>` element, as it is part of the layout of the `<main>` container and it's contents.

The only solution I can think about is putting `<main>` element in the code before `<header>` and visuall positioning header on top by Flexbox CSS property `order`. That is still not satisfying, because that would break the logical order of HTML markup, which would cause weird tab order behaviour (`<main>` elements would be tabbed by first, though they would be visually under the elements from `<header>`) and because of the same reason make site less accessible for someone using a screen reader.

I think there must be some better, more straightforward solution; especially that my scenario seems to be a really common one.

Answer (score 1):

> The only solution I can think about is putting  element in the
>   code before  and visual positioning header on top by Flexbox
>   CSS property order.

**Source-ordering** is the correct approach in this situation. Personally, I would give `<main>` a `margin-top` and `<header>` a `position: absolute`, but `flexbox` will also do the job.

> That is still not satisfying, because that would break the logical
>   order of HTML markup, which would cause weird tab order behaviour
>   ( elements would be tabbed by first, though they would be
>   visually under the elements from ) and because of the same
>   reason make site less accessible for someone using a screen reader.

You are right that accessibility is an important consideration when **source-ordering**.

The solution is to use the `tabindex` attribute:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

**eg.** Give everything in the `<header>` a `tabindex="0"` and give everything in `<main>` a `tabindex="1"`.

Comment: If that's the only possible solution, I might do that. The only problem is it creates an additional requirement to add `tabindex=1` to every element in `<header>`, especially problematic for elements that might be added there in the future - it might be easily forgotten/omitted, especially if some other developer will work on that code.

Comment: You could automate this with javascript by running a script on `DOMContentLoaded` which loops through `[... document.querySelectorAll('header *')]` setting `.tabIndex` to `1` on each element.